# How do I get text from web brwoser into a label in vb?

Tags: vb.net, web, browser, label

How do I get this, from my webbrowser into a label in vb?
Like.. how do do I get the "apple" into a label?

```
<div class="banana">
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Result" value="apple>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) control? It has a [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext(v=vs.110).aspx) property you could use. Otherwise, you'll have to elaborate a bit more on your issue...

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried for the label as well?

Comment: If you're going to be parsing a lot of HTML, take a look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Otherwise, maybe using [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) is an option. Also, what Jason said...

Comment: I am not sure.. What I am trying to do is instead of this:  Wb.Document.GetElementById("apple").SetAttribute("value", TextBox.Text)
I want it the other way around. So I get the information from web brwoser to vb. if that meakes any sence. Im sorry if it dosent..

Comment: So you want to show the text/value from a text box in a WebBrowser control on a Label in your application?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
YourLabel.Text = Wb.Document.GetElementById("yourId").GetAttribute("value")
```

You'll have to provide the `input` tag in the HTML document with an `id`, though. If you're not in control of the HTML, take a look at [GetElementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx).